# Installing windows patches on xp using a bat file

Tags: batch-file, installation, patch

I am attempting to install multiple patches and this is a small bit of the code, there are 259 patches to install, I have created for the bat file. Before taking it down to our ATM and trying it. Will this work?

```
@echo off

D:\dotnetfx35.exe /passive /norestart
D:\IE8-WindowsXP-KB2183461-x86-ENU.exe /passive /norestart
D:\IE8-WindowsXP-KB2360131-x86-ENU.exe /passive /norestart
D:\IE8-WindowsXP-KB2416400-x86-ENU.exe /passive /norestart
D:\IE8-WindowsXP-KB2482017-x86-ENU.exe /passive /norestart
D:\IE8-WindowsXP-KB2497640-x86-ENU.exe /passive /norestart
D:\IE8-WindowsXP-KB2530548-x86-ENU.exe /passive /norestart
D:\IE8-WindowsXP-KB2544521-x86-ENU.exe /passive /norestart
D:\IE8-WindowsXP-KB2559049-x86-ENU.exe /passive /norestart
D:\IE8-WindowsXP-KB2586448-x86-ENU.exe /passive /norestart
qchain.exe
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this style of command so that they execute sequentially.

```
start "" /w "d:\IE8-..." /passive /norestart
```

I make no comment about your switches and assume you know what it meant to go there.

Comment: Foxdrive, Thank you for this. I am assuming the /w is the /WAIT flag. I will test and see the results.

Comment: Tested and accomplishes desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid hard coding the name of all the hotfixes and instead rely on a for do loop like you can see here: http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/152020-batch-script-for-windows-software-updates-installation/

Comment: Glytzhkof, Thank you for your response. I am not worried about reusing this bat for future use, I have made a DVD and will not be adding patches in the future. I am researching a solution to remotely manage the updates in the future (once we upgrade to windows 7)